How do i create this corner rectangle cutout shape
Given is my website design
But i am unable to build shapes
Like in the left bar
you can see a rectangle with a cutout
so could anyone please tell me how can i create that?
I was able to create that shape but unable to make border-radius for the corners

I tried clip-path, polygon, ::before chatgpt
and other many webs nothing worked
so i thought someone might be able to help me here :D

https://css-shape.com/inverted-radius/

Works well with clip-path:
For the rounded parts, I first created an svg here and converted it to clip-path here
For the borders, you can refer to this answer


.cropped {
  width: 200px;
  aspect-ratio: 9/16;
  background: red;
  clip-path: polygon( 0% 42.857%,0% 28.571%,0% 28.571%,0.35% 26.636%,1.3% 25.086%,2.7% 23.879%,4.4% 22.971%,6.25% 22.321%,8.1% 21.886%,9.8% 21.621%,11.2% 21.486%,12.15% 21.436%,12.5% 21.429%,25% 21.429%,25% 21.429%,25.35% 21.421%,26.3% 21.371%,27.7% 21.236%,29.4% 20.971%,31.25% 20.536%,33.1% 19.886%,34.8% 18.979%,36.2% 17.771%,37.15% 16.221%,37.5% 14.286%,37.5% 7.143%,37.5% 7.143%,37.85% 5.207%,38.8% 3.657%,40.2% 2.45%,41.9% 1.543%,43.75% 0.893%,45.6% 0.457%,47.3% 0.193%,48.7% 0.057%,49.65% 0.007%,50% 0%,87.5% 0%,87.5% 0%,90.888% 0.2%,93.6% 0.743%,95.713% 1.543%,97.3% 2.514%,98.438% 3.571%,99.2% 4.629%,99.663% 5.6%,99.9% 6.4%,99.988% 6.943%,100% 7.143%,100% 7.143%,100% 15.714%,100% 24.286%,100% 32.857%,100% 41.429%,100% 50%,100% 58.571%,100% 67.143%,100% 75.714%,100% 84.286%,100% 92.857%,100% 92.857%,99.988% 93.057%,99.9% 93.6%,99.663% 94.4%,99.2% 95.371%,98.438% 96.429%,97.3% 97.486%,95.713% 98.457%,93.6% 99.257%,90.888% 99.8%,87.5% 100%,12.5% 100%,12.5% 100%,12.15% 99.993%,11.2% 99.943%,9.8% 99.807%,8.1% 99.543%,6.25% 99.107%,4.4% 98.457%,2.7% 97.55%,1.3% 96.343%,0.35% 94.793%,0% 92.857%,0% 42.857% );
}
<div class="cropped"></div>




This post has -2 Votes so i thought i might never know how to :D Thanks a lot YOu helped me a ton

ahah glad i could help
